# Export to excel directly to .xls not to html

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

Below is  code to export to excel my GridView but to format HTML. After I was exported I need to import this file to system which accept only original .xls file. Is it  way to save gridview directly to orginal .xls format?

```
protected void Btn_Excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string kodowanie = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;//aby widział polskie znaki
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "ImportWZ" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xls"));
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);


        if (ViewState["CheckBoxArray"] != null)
        {
            ArrayList CheckBoxArray = (ArrayList)ViewState["CheckBoxArray"];
            string checkAllIndex = "chkAll-" + GridView1.PageIndex;
            int rowIdx = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
                row.Visible = false;

                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    if (CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(i + 1) != -1)
                    {
                        row.Visible = true;
                        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                        row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

                        rowIdx++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#003389");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("color", "white");
        GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(kodowanie+sw.ToString());
        Response.End();

}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
{

}
```

Comment: EPPLUS can export to xlsx

Comment: Does it accept Open Office Spreadsheet/Excel 2007 (.xlsx) files?

Comment: No, I say more. They only accept older .xls (97-2003) format.

Comment: First thing you should do is yell at them for not accepting .xlsx files. Tell them that are not intelligent, and then point them towards the [compatibility pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3) that enables Excel 2003 to open .xlsx files. Then if they absolutely won't accept .xlsx files, yell at them some more. Then you'll need to either find a converter program, or *gasp* use Office Interop on the server which Microsoft strongly recommends against and is going to cause you lots of headaches. Honestly, I'd refuse to support .xls if I were you.

Comment: Another workaround might be to save the file as HTML but give it the `.xls` extension, but Excel will complain every time you open the file that it might be corrupted (but will stop open it). You are very limited in how you can style it however. And I wouldn't do it by rendering the GridView to a string. Instead I'd use Razor Engine or manually build up the HTML string so you can have absolute control over the generated HTML.

Comment: Or if style isn't important, then a CSV or semi-colon separated values file might work.

Comment: My export works fine to html with .xls extension but user after saved need to convert file to orginal .xls. In other hand our system developer said that .xls file is the only one way to import. Mayby do this in future.

Comment: _".xls file is the only way to import"_ - sounds absurd on the surface. At the basic level, assuming your html spits out correctly (tables), it can be opened by Excel, and `Saved As`...just like what was mentioned - e.g. csv, tsv. Even [Office XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) without needing any "special" component (all the way back to Office 2000 if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: EdSF look above. I wrote that export work fine and user open it in excel but before import they need to convert it to xls, exactly Save to... . I asked about export to orginal .xls and this is a topic!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an Excel library that supports xls files, like [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library) for example.

If you decide to EasyXLS, take a look at their code sample about [exporting GridView to Excel in C#](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-gridview-to-excel.html).